# What is the maximum number of iTunes Connect users allowed?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We usually add users as Internal testers and give them enough privileges to  download the app through TestFlight. Right now I have 24 users registered nearly half are clients testing the App.

Is there a limit to how many people I can add? I found only one website claiming it's 25. Also the Apple documentation on this doesn't mention anything about the limit.

P.S if possible can you link a source so I can make a claim that we should be using External testers.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com for this non-programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the oficial [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

For internal testing:

> Each app can be tested by up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Developer or Admin role in iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to 10 devices.

For External Testing:

> You can invite up to 10,000 testers using just their email address.

Hope this helps!

Update 2021 (thanks @shim), now you can have up to 100 team members and 10.000 external testers

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @O.Keskin No problem!

Comment: The max limit for external testers have been increased to 10,000

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is how many members may be allowed in the team?

Comment: @funkybro up to 25 members of your **team**  kind of says it, don't you think?

Comment: @Nick not really, it is up to 25 selected members, out of an infinite number who may be in your team?

Comment: Looks like it's up to 100 members now (according to Apple Developer site linked in post)